# Single row to multiple rows with column combination

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I have a table like this:

```
╔═════╦═══════╦════╦════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╦════╦════╗
║ ZIP ║ STATE ║ F  ║ C  ║ F1  ║ c1  ║ f2  ║ c2  ║ f3 ║ c3 ║
╠═════╬═══════╬════╬════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╬════╬════╣
║ A   ║ AS    ║ AF ║ AC ║ AF1 ║ AC1 ║ AF2 ║ AC2 ║    ║    ║
║ B   ║ BS    ║ BF ║ BC ║ BF1 ║ BC1 ║     ║     ║    ║    ║
╚═════╩═══════╩════╩════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╩════╩════╝
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
╔═════╦═══════╦═════╦═════╗
║ ZIP ║ STATE ║  F  ║  C  ║
╠═════╬═══════╬═════╬═════╣
║ A   ║ AS    ║ AF  ║ AC  ║
║ A   ║ AS    ║ AF1 ║ AC1 ║
║ A   ║ AS    ║ AF2 ║ AC2 ║
║ B   ║ BS    ║ BF  ║ BC  ║
║ B   ║ BS    ║ BF1 ║ BC1 ║
╚═════╩═══════╩═════╩═════╝
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Given this test data:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ZIP sql_variant NOT NULL,
    STATE sql_variant NOT NULL,
    F sql_variant NULL,
    C sql_variant NULL,
    F1 sql_variant NULL,
    C1 sql_variant NULL,
    F2 sql_variant NULL,
    C2 sql_variant NULL,
    F3 sql_variant NULL,
    C3 sql_variant NULL
);

INSERT @T 
    (ZIP, STATE, F, C, F1, C1, F2, C2)
VALUES 
    ('A', 'AS', 'AF', 'AC', 'AF1', 'AC1', 'AF2', 'AC2');

INSERT @T 
    (ZIP, STATE, F, C, F1, C1)
VALUES 
    ('B', 'BS', 'BF', 'BC', 'BF1', 'BC1');
```

One way to produce the desired output is:

```
SELECT
    T.ZIP,
    T.STATE,
    CA.F,
    CA.C
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES
        (F, C),
        (F1, C1),
        (F2, C2),
        (F3, C3)
) AS CA (F, C)
WHERE
    CA.F IS NOT NULL
    OR CA.C IS NOT NULL;
```